# Are the backpacks with ventilation mesh convenient for backpacking?

Tags: luggage, gear, backpacking

I did not find any official name for those backpacks, but they are characterized by a curved steel frame and a mesh, that allow good ventilation. Deuter sells them in their "Futura" line. The advantage of those packs is that they are ultra comfortable, as the mesh is adjustable and elastic. The cons are that you get less volume for the same size and long, rigid items do not fit well inside.

Are those backpacks convenient for backpacking? Maybe they have another pros and cons I have not mentioned?

Comment: If you are going on lots of flights, you should consider if it is possible to enclose the straps so that they will not get caught during baggage handling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those backpacks are very comfortable and they help to reduce the back sweating we all have experienced during long trips.
I think the choice depends greatly on the type of trip you are planning to take. If you are leaving for a, let's say, three day trek where you don't need much stuff with you, and you will likely have the backpack with you at all times, then that is the perfect choice for minimizing fatigue. If, instead, you are leaving for a month trip in, eg, middle east where you need much more space and you won't likely have the backpack with you all day (because you can leave it in hostels, train etc) I would go for a normal and lighter one (not to mention that usual backpack are less likely to be stolen than a fancier one)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you will sweat anyway so look out for something without mesh but some kind of air flow going.

My only backpack is this. I use it for everything, treks, travelling, hand-luggage and I take it always with me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DyA9QjggFQ

It is actually better for packing as you say.

Comment: Your opinion is based on using one or looking at a catalog?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. If you are backpacking at a place that may have precipitation (rain), then mesh isn't really a good option. I have a Gregory backpack that much better for that. If you're really stuck on using mesh, then probably want to go with a set of small to medium [packing cubes like Motodori has](https://www.facebook.com/motodorigear).

If the exterior of the backpack material is mesh, be careful not to snag it on a branch, they can rip, hence why I would recommend using cubes for inside the pack and use a good solid material interior frame pack by Gregory, REI, Kelty or Osprey.

Comment: I think you mean a backpack made of mesh. Whereas the OP mentions the meshed part of those backpacks which are designed to allow air flow between the carrier and the pack.